# CodeIgniter issue with database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am following a beginner's tutorial for CodeIgniter, but I can't get the view to load correctly because I have a database connection error.  I have followed everything step-by-step, and gone through it again several times, but not been able to fix it.  Could someone please help me, or at least explain why this is happening?

Here is the database configuration I currently have setup:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = 'helloworld';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I've also autoloaded the database library with the following code:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

I would also like to point out that I am using `PHP version 5.3.13`.  I not sure if the version of PHP would affect my code, so I added it anyway.

The exact error I'm getting is:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\wamp\www\CI\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124
```

Comment: That means that you have the wrong database credentials. Check again for the username and password or the database name to be sure that are correct.

Comment: The error indicates your login, hostname, or database name are not correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the hostname & db right, which just leaves the username / password.  What is the default username / password for phpmyadmin?

Comment: Are you working local? try user name root and password leave it blank: $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';

Comment: @JaPerk14 Please simply delete the question if you just had the wrong password, no one can benefit from this post.

Comment: I was also wondering, and he followed everything step by step.

Answer (score 2):

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root'; // default username if has not been set in phpmyadmin
$db['default']['password'] = ''; //leave it blank if has not been set in phpmyadmin
$db['default']['database'] = 'helloworld'; // this is your database name
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

you might have tried to import the project to work space.Instead try to traverse to the project folder through  project explorer