# Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, .htaccess, codeigniter

Actually I'm trying to configure my codeigniter live file to localhost.

I have,

1. created a database called test_bs
2. then imported the tables
3. Then change the `base_url` like `$config['base_url']=http://localhost/gu_ci/'`; and `$config['index_page']='index.php';` in config.php
4. And then did a change on database.php,Which contains

   ```
   $active_group = 'default';
   $active_record = TRUE;

   $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
   $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
   $db['default']['password'] = ' ';
   $db['default']['database'] = 'test_bs';
   $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
   $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
   $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
   $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
   $db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
   $db['default']['cachedir'] = 'application/cache/';
   $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
   $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
   $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
   $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
   $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
   ```

My .htacess file having:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /new_admin/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} PIE.htc
  AddType text/x-component .htc
  RewriteRule (.*) static/PIE.htc [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new_admin/static/

  RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php [L]
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
     A Database Error Occurred

     Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

     Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\gunify_ci\system\database\DB_driver.php

     Line Number: 124
```

I have referred [Refer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877227/codeigniter-a-database-error-occurred), [Refer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190196/codeigniter-issue-with-database),[Refer3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912508/a-database-error-occurred),[Refer4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533644/codeigniter-error-unable-to-connect-to-database-using-the-provided-settings),[Refer5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545081/codeigniter-error-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided) and so on... The last link just display the welcome message like:
[image]
But none of the solution helped me!!

Guide me to solve this!!

Comment: What do you use, WAMP Server?

Comment: Is there a space `$db['default']['password'] = ' ';` ?

Comment: yes ji....it has,but if i removed that space also no change

Comment: your database credentials seem to be wrong. Check the password that you have given is correct or not.

Comment: @HarigovindR actually where we can check our password? Because i have use a password field as empty for all other projects in php

Comment: So did you get any error lines?

Comment: No after setting db_debug to false, i don't get any error,but if set it to true i'm getting `
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\gunify_ci\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124`

Comment: @keerthi try removing the space between the quotes. Put quotes without space in between. If that dosent work we can add a new user in you database with a new password using the phpmyadmin.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you try to set `pconnect` to `FALSE`? Sometimes it works ;)

Comment: @HarigovindR i have removed the space yar....but nothing happened

Comment: @Bora i tried it earlier it would not help me

Comment: When you debug, what you get? Like your REFER4.

Comment: actually if i do run using `http://localhost/pjct_folder/name/` it simply displays 404 error, if i run using `http://localhost/gunify_ci/index.php/home`, then it displays welcome page. my default controller is `$route['default_controller'] = "Home";`

Comment: @keerthi Iam posting a link of a similer stack overflow question try the answer with 71 upvotes and try to figure out what are the errors. 
[Database connection failed with provided details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin)

Comment: @HarigovindR ok ji...will check

Comment: When i run the code `Connected OK` is displaying

Comment: now your database connection is working fine. Remove those test statements and name your default controller correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$db['default']['password'] = '';` there is an **space**, remove it

use below settings

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'test_bs';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

**Edit 01**

Use this .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**Edit 02**

your folder structurer should be

1. Application
2. assets

   - css

     1. boostrap.css
     2. style.css
   - js
   - images
3. system
4. .htacess
5. index.php

so code will be:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81286/discussion-on-answer-by-abdulla-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using).